# is there's any way that adding a material ui icon to reackMarkdown?

Tags: reactjs

Hi Im getting text data from react markdown ,

```
const exampleMarkDown=
`<ol>
<li>example1</li>
<li>example2</li>
<li>example3</li>
</ol>`
```

and the output is

```
1.example1
2.example2
3.example2
```

and I would like to add material ui icon right next to

```
1. example <ICON HERE>
```

in react component.
so is there's any way I can do that??

Answer (score 0):

You can use string literals and include the component next to the string.

```
 const exampleMarkDown=
`<ol>
<li>example1 ${<Icon>}</li>
<li>example2 ${<Icon>}</li>
<li>example3 ${<Icon>}</li>
</ol>
`
```

EDIT: Ah, i just noticed you said you're using react markdown, sorry about that. I haven't used that library before, the only thing I can think of is adding the icon in the markdown before you receive it.